# Error: InterstitialAd.show() The requested InterstitialAd has not loaded and could not be shown

Tags: react-native, expo, admob

I am creating an expo android app with react-native.
I have followed all the steps in https://docs.page/invertase/react-native-google-mobile-ads

In my App.js I added
`mobileAds().initialize() .then(adapterStatuses => { console.log('Mobile ads initialized!',adapterStatuses); }) .catch(error => { console.error('Error initializing mobile ads:', error); });`

It is loading twice. (Mobile ads initialized! is printed twice) with state 1 and name as com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds

In my reward js, I tried `RewardedAd.createForAdRequest` method to load Test rewards as well as using hook `useRewardedAd`, `useInterstitialAd`. I have called the load method in both the cases and it logs that the load has been called.

I have added my android_app_id in the app.json under the key `react-native-google-mobile-ads`

Yet I keep getting the same error. The ad doesn't seem to load even in test or with proper ad unit id value either. Please help!

AndroidManifest.xml - `com.google.android.gms.ads.DELAY_APP_MEASUREMENT_INIT` is set as false